# How to merge columns with duplicate values and keep max value from a different column in Python?

Tags: python, duplicates, max

I want to find duplicate values for "reference" column and then keep from duplicates only the row where maximum amount from "amount" column is found.

Current:

```
+----------+---------------------+---------+
| reference | amount | column3   | column4 |
+----------+---------------------+---------+
|   test1   |       9 |     45   | ye      |
|   test1   |      200|     45   | agag    |
|   test1   |      1  |     45   | aaa     |
|   test2   |      99 |     45   | bbab    |
|   test1   |      11 |     45   | value   |
+----------+---------------------+----------+
```

Desired:

```
+----------+---------------------+---------+
| reference | amount | column3   | column4 |
+----------+---------------------+---------+
|   test1   |      200|     45   | agag    |
|   test2   |      99 |     45   | bbab    |
```

Please share a clue about this situation.

Comment: What's the format of your data and what did you tried so far?

Comment: Please inform which data type you are using. You could basically use group by and find max value from each group.

Comment: it's a csv file. I have tried to find duplicate rows. I will keep digging

Comment: Does output row order matter?

Comment: No. because afterwards I can sort by column "reference" using itemgetter

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following would be a good start:

```
import csv, collections

with open("mydata.csv", 'r') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    # Assuming the first row contains the heading names, otherwise remove.
    headings = csv_input.next()     
    d_max_rows = collections.OrderedDict()

    for cols in csv_input:
        reference = cols[0]
        if reference in d_max_rows:
            cur_max = d_max_rows[reference]
            if int(cols[1]) >= int(cur_max[1]):
                d_max_rows[reference] = cols
        else:
            d_max_rows[reference] = cols

lrows = [headings] + list(d_max_rows.itervalues())

for reference, amount, col3, col4 in lrows:
    print "%-15s %-10s %-10s %-10s" % (reference, amount, col3, col4)
```

This will give you the following output:

```
reference        amount     column3    column4  
test1            200        45         agag     
test2            99         45         bbab
```

Comment: That is great news. Do not forget to up vote any useful replies and accept your preferred answer when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that does what you want:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import csv

Record = namedtuple('Record', 'reference amount column3 column4')

no_dups = {}
with open('references.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    for rec in map(Record._make, csv.reader(csvfile)):
        if (rec.reference not in no_dups or
            int(no_dups[rec.reference].amount) < int(rec.amount)):
            no_dups[rec.reference] = rec

with open('references_out.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv.writer(csvfile).writerows(rec for rec in no_dups.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is a really great python module for dealing with tabular data.  It's very much like the R language and provides a sort of in memory database.  For your example it's as simple as this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
a = df.groupby('reference')[['amount']].max()
answer = df.merge(a, on='amount')
```

And to save the result back to csv:

```
answer.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Assuming test.csv is your data file like so:

```
reference,amount,column3,column4
test1,9,45,ye
test1,200,45,agag
test1,1,45,aaa
test2,99,45,bbab
test1,11,45,value
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use groupby('reference') and agg() together where as followed agg({'amount' : 'max', 'column3' : 'max'})

Like this:

`df.groupby('reference').agg({'amount' : 'max', 'column3' : 'max'})`

Hope this helps.